# Larravel 8 вложенные запросы SQL

Tags: php, laravel, php7

Надо переписать старру програмку на веб интерфейс.
На нем есть такой запрос

```
SELECT a_c.id,a_c.name,t1.pr_no,t2.pr_no,t3.pr_no,t4.pr_no,t5.pr_no,t6.pr_no,t

FROM (SELECT pa.acode_id, p.no|| ' -' || p.name pr_no FROM parseg pa,pr p Where pa.Priority 
= 1 And pa.PrGr_ID = 1 And pa.PrGr_ID = p.PrGr_ID And pa.Pr_No = p.no) t1,

(SELECT pa.acode_id, p.no|| ' -' || p.name pr_no FROM parseg pa,pr p Where pa.Priority = 1 
And pa.PrGr_ID = 1 And pa.PrGr_ID = p.PrGr_ID And pa.Pr_No = p.no) t2,

(SELECT pa.acode_id, p.no|| ' -' || p.name pr_no FROM parseg pa,pr p Where pa.Priority = 2 
And pa.PrGr_ID = 1 And pa.PrGr_ID = p.PrGr_ID And pa.Pr_No = p.no) t3,

(SELECT pa.acode_id, p.no|| ' -' || p.name pr_no FROM parseg pa,pr p Where pa.Priority = 3 
And pa.PrGr_ID = 1 And pa.PrGr_ID = p.PrGr_ID And pa.Pr_No = p.no) t4,

(SELECT pa.acode_id, p.no|| ' -' || p.name pr_no FROM parseg pa,pr p Where pa.Priority = 4 
And pa.PrGr_ID = 1 And pa.PrGr_ID = p.PrGr_ID And pa.Pr_No = p.no) t5,

(SELECT pa.acode_id, p.no|| ' -' || p.name pr_no FROM parseg pa,pr p Where pa.Priority = 5 
And pa.PrGr_ID = 1 And pa.PrGr_ID = p.PrGr_ID And pa.Pr_No = p.no) t6
```

Как его можно реализовать на лаварель 8,не совсем понимаю.
Не хватает опыта, боль максимум делал с одним вложенным запросом.

Comment: потому что никто в здравом уме такие запросы писать не будет

Comment: Сам в шоке когда увидел.